# Spark DataFrame how to preserve sorting and partitioning information after mapPartitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, catalyst-optimizer

I use DataFrame `mapPartitions` in a library which is loosely implementation  of the [Uber Case Study](https://eng.uber.com/hdfs-file-format-apache-spark/). The output DataFrame has some new (large) columns, and the input DataFrame  is partitioned and internally sorted before doing `mapPartitions`.  Most users would project on the additional column(s)  and then aggregate on the already partitioned column. This causes an expensive redundant shuffle since `mapPartitions` use `planWithBarrier`. I wonder if there is a not-to-hacky solution for this in the catalyst api?

Code example:

```
val resultDF = keysDF
    .select("key1") //non unique
    .join(mappingTable.select("key1", "key2"), "key1") //key1->key2 many to one
    .repartition($"key2")
    .sortWithinPartitions($"key1", $"key2")
    .mapPartitions(appendThreeColumns))(RowEncoder(outputSchema))
    .select("key1", "key2", "value1", "value2", "value3")
```

As you can see, `resultDF` is partitioned by `key1` (mind the many-to-one relationship) and internally sorted.

However `resultDF.groupBy("key1").agg(count("value1"))` for example, will cause an Exchange.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I think resultDF is partitioned by key2 not key1 because you do `.repartition($"key2")`.

Comment: @astro_asz No, "mind the many-to-one relationship"

Comment: What does `.repartition($"key2")` do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry just trying to help. Try to do `resultDF.groupBy("key1").agg(count("value1")).explain()` and look for lines `Exchange hashpartitioning` which will tell you what your df is partitioned on. keysDF is partitioned on key1, and after join it is still only partitioned on key1, then it is shuffled on key2 in repartition(key2) (after which It is not longer partitioned by key1) and then shuffles again on key1 for groupBy.

Comment: @astro_asz I appreciate your help but you seem to miss the question - Spark does not even know about `repartition(key2)` because of the analysis barrier. Also, there is a many-to-one relationship between `key1` and `key2` so the output DataFrame is partitioned by both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating a few more columns with `mapPartitions` logic the applying aggregate operations due to this you are getting a lot of shuffles across multiple executors. So Spark has a bucketing concept. Please follow this [link](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-bucketing.html). Use this concept before `mapPartitions` then try for aggregations after `mapPartitions`. I think it will reduce network I/O.

Comment: Thanks Ravi :)  I guess the question was badly described because bucketing has very little to do with it. I will add more details